# Unity OpenXR Read trigger and grip data from VR controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, openxr

I´m having trouble using the new action based input system in Unity OpenXR.

I want to update the Animator objects with the values of the `ActionBasedController`. In general this works but only delivers 0 or 1. This way the animation looks simple. I´m looking for a way to read real floats so the animation only changes partially.

This is my code to read the trigger and grip value:

```
ActionBasedController controller = GetComponent<ActionBasedController>();
handAnimator.SetFloat("Trigger", controller.activateAction.action.ReadValue<float>());
handAnimator.SetFloat("Grip", controller.selectAction.action.ReadValue<float>());
```

I´ve tried to research about the topic, but I only find answers about the old input system.

Any help or new idesas are greatly appreciated.

In case it´s neede I´m using Unity 2020.3.4f1 and I'm using the OpenXR plugin version 1.0.3.

Answer (score 2):

In your default action inputs you should also have a select action value which returns an axis value. In your code you are accessing the button value here which will give you a 0 or a 1. So if you want the values in between 0 and 1 your code should be:

```
ActionBasedController controller = GetComponent<ActionBasedController>();
handAnimator.SetFloat("Trigger", controller.activateActionValue.action.ReadValue<float>());
handAnimator.SetFloat("Grip", controller.selectActionValue.action.ReadValue<float>());
```

Comment: Yes with the new Version it is way easier. In the old Version you had to change ist from Button to Value with Axis.